# How to deal with sprites and TextureRegions on AndEngine for Android

Tags: android, andengine

Imagine we have a sprite that contains all our necessary assets in one texture. In this example, three circles (all them in just one texture):

[image]

Imagine that I need to render a specific region of such sprite, for example this one:

[image]

How should we do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to use [TexturePacker](http://www.texturepacker.com/) and [AndEngine TexturePackerExtension](http://code.google.com/p/andenginetexturepackerextension/). You'll need to separate the images first though, then pack them using TexturePacker and then load it using TexturePackerExtension.

Other way is to use TextureAtlas and extract TextureRegion from it and then use that region for Sprite. See BasePhysicsJointExample in AndEngine examples how you can use it to extract TextureRegion from atlas. You'll have to provide x, y coordinates and width, height of the images in the atlas.